# laravel eloquent Filter relations Model values with Base Model id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, raw

```php
$subTasks = SubTask::with(['task']) 
    ->with(['users.subTaskInfos' => function ($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        $q->where('sub_task_id', '=', ?);
    }])
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->get();
```

I want to pass Base Model SubTask id in question mark section to filter out relations data and relation collection of data. Can anyone help?

Comment: is your sub_task_id a foreign key then you don't have to link laravel will do that for you

Comment: @bhucho I guess the users associated with a SubTask **can** have SubTaskInfos which are not related with the SubTask - maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you are attempting is to lazy eager load `users.subTaskInfos` - keeping the number of queries the same

```php
$subtasks = SubTask::with(['task'])->where('active', 1)->get();

$subtasks->load(['users.subTaskInfos' => function($q) use($subtasks) {
    $q->whereIn('sub_task_id', $subtasks->pluck('id')
        ->orderByDesc('created_at');
});
```